# Why does Typescript use the keyword "export" to make classes and interfaces public?

Tags: typescript, module, public, access-modifiers

While dabbling with Typescript I realised my classes within modules (used as namespaces) were not available to other classes unless I wrote the `export` keyword before them, such as:

```
module some.namespace.here
{
   export class SomeClass{..}
}
```

So now I can use the above code like this:

```
var someVar = new some.namespace.here.SomeClass();
```

However I was just wondering why this keyword is used opposed to just using the `public` keyword which is used at method level to signify that a method or property should be externally accessible. So why not just use this same mechanism to make classes and interfaces etc externally visible?

This would give resulting code like:

```
module some.namespace.here
{
   public class SomeClass{..}
}
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The primary reason is that `export` matches the plans for ECMAScript. You could argue that "they should have used "export" instead of "public", but asides from "export/private/protected" being a poorly matched set of access modifiers, I believe there is a subtle difference between the two that explains this.

In TypeScript, marking a class member as `public` or `private` has no effect on the generated JavaScript. It is simply a design / compile time tool that you can use to stop your TypeScript code accessing things it shouldn't.

With the `export` keyword, the JavaScript adds a line to add the exported item to the module. In your example: `here.SomeClass = SomeClass;`.

So conceptually, visibility as controlled by `public` and `private` is just for tooling, whereas the `export` keyword changes the output.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I assume that the decision was as you say to avoid having to check the context of the keyword, which is a shame as it feels like its something that will trip a few people up and really has no logical difference in behaviour to how you expect public to act, just makes their implementaiton easier.

Comment: It is necessary if you are using modules. If you app is toward the larger side, modules are typically a better choice than creating big bundles / loading all your files up front.

Comment: @Fenton Didn't you mean "you could argue that they should have used 'public' instead of 'export' ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista you could certainly argue it that way round as well, especially if your background was Java / C# rather than JavaScript.

Answer (score 54):

A few things to add to Steve Fenton's answer:

- `export` *already* means two different things (depending on whether it's at top-level or not); making it mean a third is probably worse than adding `public`/`private`
- It's definitely not to make the implementation easier; the added complexity of `public` vs `export` is trivial. We've changed keywords around a bunch already; it's not difficult.
- The default visibility of class members *must* be public to align with the ES6 class proposal, therefore we need some keyword to indicate "not public". There isn't a suitable antonym to `export` (`unexport`??), so `private` is the logical choice. Once you have `private`, it would be somewhat insane to not choose `public` as its counterpart
- Use of `export` to modify visibility in internal modules is the best-guess alignment with ES6 modules

Comment: thanks for the additional information, I completely agree with the public/private being at member level, I just found it odd not to be sufficient for all levels of access. However this is a personal opinion and a keyword is a keyword, just wanted to find out more.

Comment: I am confused by the first bullet point. Who is suggesting that `export` should have a third meaning?

Comment: BTW,  I assume someone has implicitly done this, but my TS instincts are not good enough to see the connection, and I would like to understand. (Really not liking the 5 minute edit rule.)

Comment: I agree with some of what you're saying but I disagree with the statement "There isn't a suitable antonym to export" -  "import" is the antonym, and is what TypeScript uses, when you define an exportable class, you then import it into other files

```export class User {
name: string
}```

Another file:

```import {User} from ""./the_file_path_to_the_user_class;```

see section 3.3 of the nativescript docs here http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3

Comment: How would using `import` to indicate "this value is *not exported*" be a suitable use of the keyword?

Comment: "There isn't a suitable antonym to export (unexport??)" - a suitable antonym for export should be embargo.

Comment: restrain, withhold, reserve? nothing quite cuts it!