# What is the difference between export and public in typescript?

Tags: typescript, public

I think this is a different slant on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760462/why-does-typescript-use-the-keyword-export-to-make-classes-and-interfaces-publ). And maybe the question is better phrased, when would you use public, as opposed to export? From my reading it seems like anywhere a C#/Java person thinks public, what you actually want is export.

When/where would you use public instead of export?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`public` as a visibility modifier technically does nothing (all class members are public by default); it exists as an explicit counterpart to `private`. It's legal only inside classes.

`export` does two different things depending on its context (on a top-level member in a file or in a `module` block).

At the top level of a file, `export` means that the containing file is an *external module* (i.e. it will be loaded using RequireJS, Node's `require` command, or some other CommonJS/AMD-compliant loader) and that the symbol you put `export` on should be an exported member of that external module.

Inside a `module` block, `export` means that the specified member is visible outside that module block. The default for things in `module` blocks is "closure privacy" -- unexported objects are not visible outside the module. When a declaration inside a `module` has the `export` modifier, it instead becomes a property of the module object that can be accessed from outside the module.

There is no place in the language where both `public` and `export` are legal, so choosing is relatively easy in that regard.

Comment: Ok, so module and class I use export when I think public (from C#/Java). But for functions and variables in the class, are they also marked as export? Or are they by default public and no export is needed?

Comment: There is no concept of "export" inside a class. All members are public by default.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's definitely weird to me that it's export instead of public. I understand that what happens in javascript is a bit different, but still public should then implicitly mean export too I think.

Comment: Really good answer of a confusing topic! maybe top level export should have a different name, even if maybe there are low level similarities look like an important difference and compiler error are also not clear.

Comment: Does the module itself ever need to have the export qualifier?

Answer (score 3):

`export` is specifically for modules e.g.:

```
module foo{
    export var bar;
}
```

`public` is for class members / methods e.g.:

```
class Foo{
    public bar = 123;
}
```

If you want to learn more about modules I did a video on that : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1