# What is difference between exports.function_name = code_for_function and export function_name = code_for_function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to typescript and I am working on a firebase project where I want to use cloud functions for updating some values in cloud firestore. I wanted to know what's the difference between `exports.function_name = code_for_function` and `export function_name = code_for_function`, so that I can use them appropriately.

I saw `exports.function_name` being used in [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and `export function_name` being used in a [YouTube video by firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA). So I wanted to know the difference and use cases.

I did read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169359/what-is-the-difference-between-export-and-exports-in-typescript) though it was regarding modules and not functions so I wasn't sure if the same is applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exports.XXX` is [the older CommonJS (CJS) export syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#exports-shortcut).

`export XXX` is [the currently dominant MJS standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

I'd recommend using the latter.