# How can I declare public and private variables in Typescript with interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
interface IIndexable<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}

class AdminBase {

    ExamStatusId: IIndexable<IEnumElement> = {
        All: {
            elem: "",
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: {
            elem: "asdf",
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving me an error saying:

```
Error   5   Public property 'ExamStatusId' of exported class has or is 
using private type 'IEnumElement'.  C:\Protractor\Latest\TypeScript1.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the issue appears, once you start to export the AdminBase class. As nicely explained here:

- [Why does Typescript use the keyword "export" to make classes and interfaces public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760462/)

What we have to do, is to export the intefaces as well

```
export interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
export interface IIndexable<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}

export class AdminBase {

    ExamStatusId: IIndexable<IEnumElement> = {
        All: {
            elem: "",
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: {
            elem: "asdf",
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
}
```