# Why is it not possible to export a class instance in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I didn't find a way to export a class instance easily in TypeScript. I had to come up with the following workaround to generate proper javascript code.

```
 var expo = new Logger("default");
 export = expo;
```

generates

```
var expo = new Logger("default");
module.exports = expo;
```

Is there an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: It exists something, you should read

[Why does Typescript use the keyword “export” to make classes and interfaces public?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760462/why-does-typescript-use-the-keyword-export-to-make-classes-and-interfaces-publ

Comment: What code were you trying to write? It seems like you've accomplished your goal?

Comment: I wanted to write `export new Logger("default");`. Hm... still don't find it very  clear. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I had to come up with the following workaround to generate proper javascript code

Not a workaround. This is the standard way in TS to do a root level export.

> Is there an easier way of achieving this

Yes. `export = new Variable`. Example:

```
export = new Foo();
```

## Future

For ES modules you should instead use a `default` export:

```
export default expo = new Logger("default");
```

Which will in most cases have the same effect as a root level export.

Comment: Added a `Yes` / `No` answer. I don't see it answered in any of the other answers on the page.

Comment: Good on you for improving this 3 years after the fact (not sarcasm)!

Answer (score 20):

Quite by accident, I found this way to export an instance:

```
class MyClass(){}

export default new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 5):

On https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern is an additional way of doing this:

```
export let expo = new Logger("default");
```

Which has the advatage that it is possible to export several class instances in a *.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a static instance inside a class:

```
export class MyClass {
  static instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
} 

..

var instanceOfMyClass = MyClass.instanceOfMyClass;
```